# Erro na exibição das informações do dicionario

Tags: python, funções, dicionário

sou inciante em python e estou com uma dificuldade no seguinte codigo:

```
    class Gerador:
    def __init__(self, nome, potencia, capacidade_energia, capacidade_combustivel):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__status = None
        self.__potencia = potencia
        self.__capacidade_energia = capacidade_energia
        self.__tanque_combustivel = 0                           
        self.__capacidade_combustivel = capacidade_combustivel 

    def abastecer(self, litros): # abastecer geradores
        if self.__tanque_combustivel + litros <= self.__capacidade_combustivel:
            self.__tanque_combustivel += litros
            print("\nTanque abastecido")
        else:
            print("Erro. Ultrapassou a capacidade")

    def acionamento(self, estado, nome_gerador): # acionar geradores
        self.__nome == nome_gerador
        if nome_gerador == 'G1':
            print('\nATENÇÃO\nG1 não é gerenciado manualmente!')
        elif  estado == '1':
            estado = 'ligado'   
            print(nome_gerador, 'foi ligado!')
        elif estado == '2':
            estado = 'desligado'
            print(nome_gerador, 'foi desligado')
        else:
            print('opção invalida')

    def get(self, nome):
        return self.__nome

    def status_gerador(self, geradores, estado):
        for n in geradores:  
          print (n, geradores[n],[estado])

    def get_status(self):   
        return self.__status

#programa principal
g1 = Gerador("G1", 2000, 1000, 300)
g2 = Gerador("G2", 1300, 530, 435)
g3 = Gerador("G3", 1200, 520, 420)
g4 = Gerador("G4", 1100, 510, 410)  

# abastecimento dos geradores
nome_gerador = input('\nInforme o Nome do Gerador: ')
nome_gerador = nome_gerador.upper()
litros = int(input ('\nQuantidade de Litros: '))
if nome_gerador == 'G1':
    g1.abastecer(litros)# chama o metodo do objeto correspondente
if nome_gerador == 'G2':
    g2.abastecer(litros)
if nome_gerador == 'G3':
    g3.abastecer(litros)
if nome_gerador == 'G4':
    g4.abastecer(litros)

# acionamento dos geradores
nome_gerador = input('\nnome do gerador: ')
nome_gerador = nome_gerador.upper()
print('\ndeseja ligar o gerador ' +nome_gerador+'?\n')
print('1.sim \n2.não\n')
estado = input('Digite: ') 
estado = estado.lower()
if nome_gerador == 'G1':
    g1.acionamento(estado, nome_gerador)
elif nome_gerador == 'G2':
    g2.acionamento(estado, nome_gerador)
elif nome_gerador == 'G3':
    g3.acionamento(estado, nome_gerador)
elif nome_gerador == 'G4':
    g4.acionamento(estado, nome_gerador)
else:
    print('O gerador não existe')

# status dos geradores
print('\nSTATUS DOS GERADORES:')
geradores = {'G1': g1.get_status(), 'G2': g2.get_status(), 'G3': g3.get_status(), 'G4': g4.get_status()}  
g1.status_gerador(geradores, estado)
```

quando chamo o a função "status_gerador" ela me traz o dicionario com resultados como, "None" e a opção digita quando a função "acionamento" foi chamada, quando na verdade o que se esperava era o nome do gerador e sua atualização (ligado ou desligado), ex: "G2 ligado". É importante deixar claro que não desejo a solução completa do meu problema, apenas um "norte" a seguir, desde já muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Recomendo estudar um pouco mais orientação a objetos, pois a sua classe `Gerador` não tá fazendo muito sentido, especialmente os métodos `acionamento` e `status_gerador`.

Answer (score 0):

Existe algumas boas modificações que poderiam ser feitas no seu código, como uma diminuição na quantidade de condições, entre outras, mas isso acontece, e com o tempo você irá trabalhando esses detalhes, sendo assim, focando no seu questionamento tenho as seguintes observações:

Logo no construtor da classe, você estabelece que **self._status = None**, mas em nenhum momento no seu código você atualiza esse valor para qualquer outro, acho que houve alguma confusão entre esse atributo da classe com a variável **estado**, que no caso, pode ser 1 ou 2, a depender da entrada do usuário.

Bom, algumas modificações que poderiam ser feitas, seriam as seguintes:

```
def __init__(self, nome, potencia, capacidade_energia, capacidade_combustivel,status=False):
  #.....
  self.__status = status
```

Ou seja, no construtor você define um argumento opcional, que se não for passado, ja será definido com False, que nessa situação representaria **desligado**.

Além disso, perceba que no seu método **acionamento**, você esta setando o estado para **ligado** ou **desligado**, o que creio eu, deveria ser o **self_status** que deveria está sendo modificado. Exemplo:

```
def acionamento(self, estado, nome_gerador): # acionar geradores
  #.........
  elif  estado == '1':
      self.__status = True
```

Sendo assim, so será necessário voce lidar com a saída, sendo ligado' se for True, e desligado se for False.

Fazendo dessa forma, o estado nem precisaria ser passado como argumento em seu método **status_gerador**.

Answer (score -1):

amigo, acredito que você deveria definir o estado inicial como diferente de `none` ou, pra facilitar nos código, usar `True` como ligado e `False` como desligado, por meio de um método que avalia o estado.

Caso o gerador 1 seja diferente dos demais, considere fazer uma classe mãe para os geradores, uma classe gerador genérica e uma classe pro gerador 1, já que ele é específico.